# MSSQL to VB.NET conversion

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, command

I'm working on a projec which is converting T-SQL procedures into VB.NET code and I've been thinking about how to write something neat, clean in VB.NET.

For example, this is the T-SQL :

```
insert into X(
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100) 
select 
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100 
 from Y
```

How should I convert this statement into VB.NET? If I use string builder, it would be something like :

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
With sb
    .Append("Insert into x(")
    .Append("column1,")
    .Append("column2,")
    .Append("...,")
    ......
End With
```

THe code would be too long. Is there any better alternatives?

Comment: you provide no context so maybe my comment is not suitable to your environment but the neat and clean way to write that is a stored procedure; if you embed sql code into vb.net you will not use some of the key features/advantages of sql-server (eg: you lose execution plans). also be aware that you expose the application to possible sql injection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since unfortunately there are no verbatim string literals like in C# where you could write this:

```
string insertSQL = @"
insert into X(
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100) 
select 
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100 
 from Y 
";
```

you could use XML literals to get a similar behaviour:

```
Dim insertSQL As String = <![CDATA[ 
insert into X(
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100) 
select 
 column1, 
 column2, 
 ....., 
 column100 
 from Y 
]]>.Value
```

The verbose classic way is to use:

```
Dim insertSQL As String = "insert into X( " & vbCrLf &
                          "column1, " & vbCrLf &
                          "column2,  " & vbCrLf &
                          ".....,  " & vbCrLf &
                          "column100)  " & vbCrLf &
                          "select  " & vbCrLf &
                          "column1,  " & vbCrLf &
                          "column2,  " & vbCrLf &
                          ".....,  " & vbCrLf &
                          "column100  " & vbCrLf &
                          "from Y  "
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I do not have the reputation to put this as a "comment" but based on my experience LINQ has helped me a lot in shortening SQL procedures.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386946(v=vs.110).aspx